# Is there a method to check if an array has ANY value in it?

Tags: javascript

Say I want to have an if statement to test if an array is empty or not,
Looking it up I have found no way to check besides array[0], which in frameworks like React and Angular give errors on the array's item not existing.

```
let arr = [];

if (!arr[0]) {
  arr.map(val=>{
    return <div>{val.name}</div>  
  });
}
```

In this example I want it to Display the JSX and if not, do not display any JSX. But doing this throws an error. Is there anyway to do this? preferably without any outside libraries.

edit: "added 'this' after 'to do'"

Comment: If the array has no elements, what's wrong with just returning the `arr.map`? It'll return an empty array too, which means nothing would be rendered, I think?

Comment: Maybe just check if `arr.length > 0`?  But it's not really clear what the actual problem is.  Iterating over an empty array doesn't produce an error, it just doesn't iterate.  Which makes this sound like an XY Problem.

Answer (score 4):

This checks whether the variable is defined and whether it contains anything (although in this case you'd probably not need the first check):

```
if ( arr && arr.length )
```

Also, don't forget to `return arr.map(...`

Comment: Thanks, arr.length never even crossed my mind, but for every time i run across this specific situation it would work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not even certain your variable even is an array, this is what I would do:

```
if (Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length) { /*...*/ }
```

For your special case you probably don't even need the 2nd check, though, because all of the Array iterators don't run even once if the Array they are called on is empty.

Example:

```js
const arr = [];

console.log(arr.map(Number));
console.log(arr.some(parseInt));
console.log(arr.every(parseInt));
console.log(arr.filter(Number));
```

None of the methods will throw an error provide `arr` is an array.